# Why my program is not reading if else command?

Tags: python

```
def chama ():
    a = str(input('Do you want to enter another word? If Yes (Y), No (N)')).lower()
    if a == 'Y' or 'yes':
        word = []
        word.append(input('Please enter a word'))
        string = ''.join(map(str,word))
        inverse = string[::-1]
        if string == inverse:
            print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is a palindrome''')
    if a == 'N' or 'NO':
        print ('See you next time!')


chama ()
```

Comment: The second expression for the `or` is a string, which always evaluates to true for non-empty strings. You need it to be like `... or a == 'Yes'`. The same goes for the No.

Comment: But it still no showing the command

Comment: def chama ():
    a = str(input('Do you want to enter another word? If Yes (Y), No (N)')).lower()
    if a == 'Y' or a =='yes':
        word = []
        word.append(input('Please enter a word'))
        string = ''.join(map(str,word))
        inverse = string[::-1]
        if string == inverse:
            print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is a palindrome''')
    if a == 'N' or a =='NO':
        print ('See you next time!')


chama ()

Comment: Additionally, since you convert your input to lowercase using `.lower()`, it will never be equal to an uppercase string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for if statements you need to have a proper comparison after the `or`

```
if a == 'Y' or a == 'yes':
```

You are also calling `.lower()` which converts the characters to lowercase but then you are trying to compare to uppercase. So since you are converting the input to lowercase you need to make sure you are comparing to `'y' or 'yes'` and `'n' or 'no'`. This is good practice as it will allow for the user to type `n N No nO NO no` and `y Y yes Yes yEs YEs yeS YeS yES YES`

This should resolve those problems.

```
def chama():
    a = str(input('Do you want to enter another word? If Yes (Y), No (N)')).lower()
    if a == 'y' or a == 'yes':
        word = []
        word.append(input('Please enter a word'))
        string = ''.join(map(str,word))
        inverse = string[::-1]
        if string == inverse:
            print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is a palindrome''')
    if a == 'n' or a == 'no':
        print ('See you next time!')
        
chama()
```

If you want the program to repeat until the user enters `no` I would recommend just putting a while loop at the top with a `break` if the user types `no`

```
def chama():
  while True:
    a = str(input('Do you want to enter another word? If Yes (Y), No (N)')).lower()
    if a == 'y' or a == 'yes':
        word = []
        word.append(input('Please enter a word'))
        string = ''.join(map(str,word))
        inverse = string[::-1]
        if string == inverse:
            print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is a palindrome''')
        else:
            print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is NOT a palindrome''')
    if a == 'n' or a == 'no':
        print ('See you next time!')
        break
        
chama()
```

I modified the code above to have an `else` statement that would let the user know if the entered word is NOT a palindrome

Comment: Man thanks for your help!
But the program is stopping is not running as should. When ask if the user wants to continue, after add a word it doesn't give the result.

def main (): 
  string = (input('Please enter a word: '))
  reversed = ''
  for i in string: 
    reversed = i+reversed 
  if string == reversed:
    print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is a palindrome''')
  else:
    print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is not a palindrome.''')
   
main()       
chama()

Comment: @JorgedePaulaJr Well your program is setup to print the word only if it is a palindrome. What do you want it to do if the word is not a palindrome?

Comment: yes, like if is not a palindrome, the program should say print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is not a palindrome.'''). It shoud keep showing when the user say yes... like if is a palindrome or if is not

Answer (score 0):

**If you write `if a=="y" or "yes"` it will always return `true`:-**

```
>>> a=='y' or 'yes'
'yes'
>>> a="y"
>>> a=='y' or 'yes'
True
>>> a="n"
>>> a=='y' or 'yes'
'yes'
>>> bool('yes')
True
```

**This is how you can get the required result:-**

```py
def chama ():
    a = input('Do you want to enter another word? If Yes (Y), No (N): ').lower()
    if a == 'y' or a == 'yes':
        word = []
        word.append(input('Please enter a word: '))
        string = ''.join(word)
        inverse = string[::-1]
        if string == inverse:
            print ('''The word that you entered:''', string.upper(), '''is a palindrome''')
    if a == 'n' or a == 'no':
        print ('See you next time!')


chama ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write the code like:

`if a == 'y' or a == 'yes':`

and

`if a == 'n' or a == 'no':`

Reason: The one mentioned by [Bibhav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16321225/bibhav) in this post. If you write if `a=="y" or "yes"`, it will always return `true`.

Answer (score 0):

Just write the if condition correctly and your code is ready to go. Just change the line:

`if a=="Y" or "yes"` to `if a=="Y" or a=="yes"`

and the second line:

`if a=="N" or "NO"` to `if a=="N" or a=="NO"`